# Hardsub on mkv or mp4?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, mkv

I want to know why people usually use mp4 for hardsub and mkv for softsub?

Which one better for hardsub, mkv or mp4? And why?

Which one have the best performance for low-end device?

Comment: SO should not be used for broad and opinion-based questions. Please, read these links to adapt your question or post in another site from SO community: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [Topics to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you have additional questions please ask at [video.stackexchange.com](http://video.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your target devices or players can handle.

> I want to know why people usually use mp4 for hardsub and mkv for softsub?

Some devices and players support "timed text" softsubs in MP4, but not all do. Hardsubs will be viewable in any player.

> Which one better for hardsub, mkv or mp4? And why?

Hardsubs are part of the video itself, so it makes no difference if your video contains hardsubs or not. What matters is what format your device supports.

> Which one have the best performance for low-end device?

Performance wise the support of softsubs is insignificant compared to decoding video and audio, so I wouldn't use performance as a metric to decide between softsubs and hardsubs.

## Use softsubs and MKV if you can

Softsubs are superior because you don't need to re-encode the video (unlike hardsubbing), the user can turn then on/off, you can support multiple languages, and you can swap subtitle streams if you ever want to change them. Hardsubs are permanent.

MKV is superior because it can support multiple softsub formats and multiple softsub streams for multiple languages.